# Upgrade Windows Vista Enterprise to Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

I have Windows Vista Enterprise (x64) installed on my desktop.  Is it possible to upgrade this to Windows 7 Professional?  I know I could do a clean install, but I really don't want to.

I've read that if you change the `EditionID` and `ProductName` values in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, you can make the installer think you are upgrading from a correct edition version of Windows?

Will this work?  Is there anyway I can upgrade; I'd rather not do a clean install.

Comment: This article describes all of the supported upgrade paths:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can try forcing the Upgrade with the settings you've mentioned, but there's the risk of losing or damaging your entire OS setup (without the possibility of a roll-back).

There's a tool that Microsoft Provides for checking compatibility issues o your current OS installation. You should try it for having a clear idea of you situation.

[Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx)

Comment: I'll probably just clean install, that would be safer.